# How to multiply by 5%

Tags: php

how to make multiplication by 5%, for example like this.

200000 x 5% = 10000

So that's how it is?

```
 <?php
    $a = 200000;
    $b = 5;
    $x = $a % $b;
    echo $x;
?>
```

Comment: Note that for ages (at least since C language), "%" is the MODULO operator (that is, division remaining).

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplication by %"?

Comment: I mean, how do I multiply it by 5%? Can

Comment: You now probably know that since the problem is solved below but just in case, "multiplying by 5%" is actually the same than multiplying by 0.05 or, litterally, "by 5 units in a hundred", which is the same than "multiplying by (5/100)." Be aware, though, that in certain programing languages, types may matter: if you're implicitly working on integers, (5/100) will give 0, not 0.05, making troubleshooting hard and confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not convert the percentage value to a decimal and multiple?

```
$a = 200000;
$b = 5;
$x = $a * ($b / 100);
echo $x;
```

The return value will be a float.

Although, I'm still somewhat unclear as to what you are actually asking.

Comment: As long as this is what you actually wanted? Your question is somewhat confusing, bear in mind `%` is modulo in PHP and will return the remainder of $a divided by $b. Please also bear in mind the answer given above will return a float, not an integer.

Answer (score -2):

Use normal calculation to multiplication by %
Code:

```
<?php
$a = 1000;
$b = 2000;
$x = $a * 100 / 100 * $b;
echo $x;
?>
```

Comment: How is this working great? 200,000 multiplied by 5% does not equal 1,000,000?

Comment: not working code...